# fancybox iframe content cant be loaded second time

Tags: iframe, embed, fancybox-2

I´m having issues with displaying/loading iframes the second time in fancybox.

I´m embedding various Contents from different Social Media Plattforms like Facebook, Twitter, Instagram etc. within a fancybox popup.

When I click the button once to show me the popup. Everything works without issues. The iFrame loads and is displayed.

When I now close and try to open the fancybox again, the popup appears but the content is not.

To insert the iFrame I´m using jQuery.html.

I don´t even know where the issue could be. Any suggestions ?

Here is my code: Explaining it a bit more down below!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    outout = "";
    FanBox = "";
    $("#iFramePlace").load(function() {
        alert('LOAD');
        $.fancybox.reposition();
    });

    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(e) {

        var id = $('input[name="add-to-cart"]').val();
        var link = $("input[name='tmcp_textfield_1']").val();
        console.log(link);
        FanBox = $.fancybox;
        FanBox({
            //jQuery.fancybox({
            href: '#cc_add_to_cart_confirm',
            autoCenter: true,
            'closeBtn': false,
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            padding: 0,
            centerOnScroll: true,
            autoScale: true
        });
        $(this).removeClass('loading');
        if (link !== "")
            ApiRequest(link, id);
        else
            alert("LINK FEHLT");




        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#cc_add_to_cart_confirm .cc_agree').on('click', function(e) {
        //$.fancybox.reposition();
        FanBox.close();
        delete FanBox;
        FanBox = "";
        delete output;
        output = "";
        //unset output;

        $('.single_add_to_cart_button').addClass('loading').closest('form').submit();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#cc_add_to_cart_confirm .cc_disagree').on('click', function(e) {
        FanBox.close();
        delete FanBox;
        //unset FanBox;
        FanBox = "";
        delete output;
        output = "";
        //unset output;
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    function ApiRequest(l, pid) {
        $.get("apiServer/?l=" + l + "&id=" + pid, function(data) {
            var ServerResult = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(ServerResult);
            if (ServerResult.error == false) {
                if (ServerResult.platform == 'fb') {
                    output = "";
                    output += "<div id=\"fb-root\"><\/div>";
                    output += "    <script>";
                    output += "        (function(d, s, id) {";
                    output += "            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];";
                    output += "            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;";
                    output += "            js = d.createElement(s);";
                    output += "            js.id = id;";
                    output += "            js.src = \"\/\/connect.facebook.net\/de_DE\/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1281569608559738\";";
                    output += "            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);";
                    output += "        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));";
                    output += "    <\/script>";
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'fanpage') {
                        output += "<div class=\"fb-page\" data-href=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" data-small-header=\"false\" data-adapt-container-width=\"true\" data-tabs=\"timeline\" data-hide-cover=\"false\" data-show-facepile=\"false\">";
                        output += "                                     <blockquote cite=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">";
                        output += "                                 <\/div>";
                    }
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'post' || ServerResult.typ == 'photo') {
                        output += "<div class=\"fb-post\" data-href=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" data-show-text=\"true\">";
                        output += "                             <blockquote cite=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">";
                        output += "                         <\/div>";

                    }
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'video') {
                        output += "<div class=\"fb-video\" data-href=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" data-show-text=\"true\">";
                        output += "                                 <blockquote cite=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">";
                        output += "                             <\/div>";
                    }
                }
                if (ServerResult.platform == 'ig') {
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'profile') {
                        console.log(ServerResult.embedLink);
                    }
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'picture' || ServerResult.typ == 'video') {
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<blockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-version=\"7\" style=\" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);\">";
                        output += "                                         <div style=\"padding:8px;\">";
                        output += "                                             <div style=\" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:62.4537037037% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;\">";
                        output += "                                                 <div style=\" background:url(data:image\/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC\/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5\/P8\/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo\/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI\/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf\/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;\"><\/div>";
                        output += "                                             <\/div>";
                        output += "                                             <p style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;\"><a href=https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/p\/" + ServerResult.embedLink + " style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none;\" target=\"_blank\"><\/a>";
                        output += "                                                 <time style=\" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;\" datetime=\"2016-11-20T17:34:50+00:00\"><\/time>";
                        output += "                                             <\/p>";
                        output += "                                         <\/div>";
                        output += "                                     <\/blockquote>";
                        output += "                                     <script async defer src=\"\/\/platform.instagram.com\/en_US\/embeds.js\"><\/script>";

                    }
                }
                if (ServerResult.platform == 'yt') {
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'channel') {
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<script src=\"https:\/\/apis.google.com\/js\/platform.js\"><\/script>";
                        output += "<div class=\"g-ytsubscribe\" data-channelid=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\" data-layout=\"full\" data-count=\"default\"><\/div>";
                    }
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'video') {
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<div class=\"ytcontainer\">";
                        output += "<iframe src=\"\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\"frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen class=\"ytvideo\"><\/iframe>";
                        output += "<\/div>";
                    }
                }
                if (ServerResult.platform == 'dp') {
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'profile') {
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<script src=\"https:\/\/apis.google.com\/js\/platform.js\" async defer><\/script>";
                        output += "                                                 <div class=\"g-person\" data-href=\"https:\/\/plus.google.com\/" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\"><\/div>";
                    }
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'post') {
                        console.log('post');
                        console.log(ServerResult.embedLink);
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<script src=\"https:\/\/apis.google.com\/js\/platform.js\" async defer><\/script>";
                        output += "                                                 <div class=\"g-post\" data-href=\"https:\/\/plus.google.com\/" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\"><\/div>";


                    }
                }
                if (ServerResult.platform == 'tw') {
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'profile') {
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<a class=\"twitter-timeline\" data-chrome=\"noscrollbar\" data-tweet-limit=\"1\" data-theme=\"light\" href=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\">Tweets <\/a> <script async src=\"\/\/platform.twitter.com\/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"><\/script>";

                    }
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'tweet') {
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<blockquote class=\"twitter-tweet\" data-lang=\"de\"><p lang=\"de\" dir=\"ltr\"> <a href=\"" + ServerResult.embedLink + "\"><\/a><\/blockquote>";
                        output += "                                <script async src=\"\/\/platform.twitter.com\/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"><\/script>";

                    }
                }
                if (ServerResult.platform == 'sc') {
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'profile') {
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https:\/\/w.soundcloud.com\/player\/?url=https%3A\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/users\/" + ServerResult.embedLink + "&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true\"><\/iframe>";


                    }
                    if (ServerResult.typ == 'track') {
                        var output = "";
                        output += "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https:\/\/w.soundcloud.com\/player\/?url=https%3A\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/tracks\/" + ServerResult.embedLink + "&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true\"><\/iframe>";

                    }
                }
            } else
                var output = "Mit dem Link stimmt etwas nicht !";

            //output = "<iframe src='http://likepocket.de/apiServer/catchContent.php?l="+ServerResult.embedLink+"/' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen class='fb-page'></iframe>";
            $("#iFramePlace").html(output);
        });
    };
});
```

This is everything.
I´m passing a input value to a php file on my server and I´m recieving a json back. This json contains the "link" that is needed to embedd the content that I want to display and some other information to decide which kind of embedding I need to use.

Then it just gets thrown into the div with the id iFrameplace.

I hope you can see through this mess :S

Regars !

Comment: It would really help if you could post your code! Read the guidelines for asking questions please

Comment: The issue is there is so much more stuff around it. 
I´ll try to make it understandable. 
Give me a sec